# Queries with identical execution plan have significant execution time differences

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have two queries on the same fact table that feed two tables, one with daily granularity and one with hourly granularity.

```
select 
    t1.date
    ,sum(t1.col1) as col1
    ...
    ,t1.coln
    ,t2.col1
    ,t3.col1
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
left join table3 t3
on t1.id = t3.id
where 
t1.date between '20180210' and '20180211'
group by t1.date
         ,t1.col1
         ....
         ,t1.coln
         ,t2.col1
         ,t3.col1


select 
    t1.date
    ,datepart(hh,t1.datetime) as hour
    ,sum(t1.col1) as col1
    ...
    ,t1.coln
    ,t2.col1
    ,t3.col1
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
left join table3 t3
on t1.id = t3.id
where 
t1.date between '20180210' and '20180211'
and t1.cola = 'value1'
and t2.colb in ('value2','value3')
group by t1.date
         ,datepart(hh,t1.datetime) 
         ,t1.col1
         ....
         ,t1.coln
         ,t2.col1
         ,t3.col1
```

The columns are generic but everything else is exactly like my production queries. The query plan involves one table scan in table 1 which is 96% of the cost. 
These queries are scheduled to run early in the morning (5:00AM) and for daily data (the queries have to process around 200.000 rows of table1 which is the fact table) execution time is ~1min for daily and ~1,5min for hourly data.

In the rare occasion that my SSIS jobs fail, if i try to re-run the hourly query, according to sp_who2 and server monitoring, it takes extremely high cpu time, consumes all server's cpu (usage goes up to 99-100%) and query never runs. If I do not update the data and let SSIS job to run next day and load the two previous days, everything runs smoothly. 
I do not understand why the addition of datepart() function makes so much of a performance decline, where the plan and estimated cpu and I/O costs for both plans are exactly the same.

Any ideas of what I should search for?

Comment: "I do not understand why the addition of datepart() function makes so much of a performance decline". When you use a function on an attribute, an index can no longer be used. This should be evident in the execution plan though...

Comment: Columns in the where clause do not contain the datetime column so the initial table scan remains as is. Hence the difference in execution time on both queries has a reasonable difference.

Comment: My first thought would be out-of-date statistics. If you're querying over "new" data, the optimizer's estimate as to how much rows the query will involve can be wildly incorrect, with the bad plan to match -- a situation that will correct itself "automatically" after enough rows have been added. Try slotting in an `UPDATE STATISTICS` on the tables (or even `sp_updatestats`, but that's a bit more heavy-duty).

Comment: Old trick which I am already using so unfortunately it won't do...!

Comment: Then your only recourse is to replicate the slowness, and capture the actual plans as you get them, and [post them here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), because clearly there *must* be a material difference. (For another "here's a lazy fix" suggestion: you can use `WITH (RECOMPILE)` in case a bad plan is getting stuck somehow; for a query only executing once per hour, that has negligible performance impact.)